# Deserialize SOAP XML Response

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to deserialize an XML response from a web service. The response comes in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<providerDemographicsResponse xmlns="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerDemographicsResponse/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerAddress/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/expandedProvider/v1" xmlns:ns4="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/enrollmentDetails/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerBusinessEntity/v1" xmlns:ns6="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerNpoAssociation/v1" xmlns:ns7="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/serviceAreaDetail/v1" xmlns:ns8="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/networkProviderAddress/v1" xmlns:ns9="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/delegationEntity/v1" xmlns:ns10="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerSpecialty/v1" xmlns:ns11="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerNpi/v1" xmlns:ns12="http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/common/messages/metadata/v1">
  <ns12:metadata>
    <ns12:serviceReferenceId>test17-02-2016 16:05:47.000616</ns12:serviceReferenceId>
    <ns12:limit>1</ns12:limit>
    <ns12:offset>0</ns12:offset>
    <ns12:total>1</ns12:total>
    <ns12:outcome>
      <ns12:status>200</ns12:status>
      <ns12:message>Successful.</ns12:message>
      <ns12:code>200</ns12:code>
      <ns12:additionalDetails/>
    </ns12:outcome>
  </ns12:metadata>
  <data>
    <providerDemographics>
      <cpfProviderId>0000010</cpfProviderId>
      <effectiveDate>1980-01-01</effectiveDate>
      <terminationDate>9999-12-31</terminationDate>
      <provider-under-review-indicator>N</provider-under-review-indicator>
      <providerTypeDescription>Healthcare Organization</providerTypeDescription>
    </providerDemographics>
    <providerDemographics>
      <cpfProviderId>0000010</cpfProviderId>
      <effectiveDate>1980-01-01</effectiveDate>
      <terminationDate>9999-12-31</terminationDate>
      <provider-under-review-indicator>N</provider-under-review-indicator>
      <providerTypeDescription>Healthcare Organization</providerTypeDescription>
    </providerDemographics>
  </data>
</providerDemographicsResponse>
```

I have this class to get at the providerDemographics list at the bottom of the XML:

```
public class ProviderDemographics {

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cpfProviderId")]
    public int CpfProviderId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "effectiveDate")]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "terminationDate")]
    public DateTime TerminationDate { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "provider-under-review-indicator")]
    public string ProviderUnderReviewIndicator { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "providerTypeDescription")]
    public string ProviderTypeDescription { get; set; }

}
```

I tried using the regular XmlSerializer to deserialize it, but I get an exception (I think relating to the number of namespaces, but I'm not entirely sure). I also tried using Linq, but when I try parising the XDocument, I get an empty list.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var list = (from d in doc.Descendants("providerDemographics")
            select new ProviderDemographics {
                CpfProviderId = (int)d.Attribute("cpfProviderId")
            }).ToList();
```

Any idea how I can extract the providerDemographics as a list from the reponse?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the namespace when you are searching the elements. Because your wanted element doesn't have any specific **namespace** you should take the parent element namespace. In this case it is **namespace** of `providerDemographicsResponse`

**Here is working example:**

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "your provided Xml"

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XNamespace metadataNameSpace = "http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/common/messages/metadata/v1";
            XNamespace headNameSpace = "http://provapi.sys.test.com/provider/network/messages/providerDemographicsResponse/v1";

            //if you want tags providerDemographics
            var list = (from d in doc.Descendants(headNameSpace + "providerDemographics")
                        select new
                        {
                            CpfProviderId  = d.Element(headNameSpace + "cpfProviderId").Value
                        }).ToList();

            //if you want metadata tags data   
            var metaDatalist = (from d in doc.Descendants(metadataNameSpace + "metadata")
                                select d).ToList();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```